# issue with webpack-server 2

Tags: webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

When i run webpack server, it redirects me to folders of project not my index.html, but if I open it without webpack server it works fine, and nothing in network tab. I think my webpack.config.js not loaded correctely!

my webpack.confing.js :

```
    const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
var path = require("path");


module.exports = {
    entry : './src/app.js',
    output : {
        path : path.resolve(__dirname,'dist'),
        filename : 'app.bundle.js'
    },
    module : {
        rules : [
            {test: /\.scss$/, 
            loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader','sass-loader'],
                publicPath: "/dist"
            })}
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin({
            filename: "app.scss",
            disable: false,
            allChunks: true
        })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have misunderstood the public path concept that has nothing to do with file system path. That is, the publicPath is only related to the url.

```
url = `${host}:${port}${publicPath}${bundle}`
```

Only change your extract text plugin parameter publicPath for '/'