# how to remove webpack's hmr in production?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, webpack-2, webpack-hmr

I have a vs2015 solution and I use webpack.

I did set up an environment variable, but when I publish, the app is still sending hmr request 
I can see in chrome dev tools 
GET http://localhost:52112/__webpack_hmr net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

My config is :

webpack.config.js, where it looks for --env.prod

```js
var isDevBuild = process.argv.indexOf('--env.prod') < 0;
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
var merge = require('webpack-merge');
var allFilenamesExceptJavaScript = /\.(?!js(\?|$))([^.]+(\?|$))/;

// Configuration in common to both client-side and server-side bundles
var sharedConfig = {
    resolve: { extensions: [ '.js', '.ts' ] },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        publicPath: '/dist/' // Webpack dev middleware, if enabled, handles requests for this URL prefix
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, include: /ClientApp/, loader: 'ts-loader', query: { silent: true } },
            { test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'to-string-loader!css-loader' },
            { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader', query: { limit: 25000 } }
        ]
    }
};

// Configuration for client-side bundle suitable for running in browsers
var clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot-client.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, './wwwroot/dist') },
    devtool: isDevBuild ? 'inline-source-map' : 'false',
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
            context: __dirname,
            manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
        })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [] : [
        // Plugins that apply in production builds only
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ])
});

// Configuration for server-side (prerendering) bundle suitable for running in Node
var serverBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-server': './ClientApp/boot-server.ts' },
    output: {
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
        path: path.join(__dirname, './ClientApp/dist')
    },
    target: 'node',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    externals: [nodeExternals({ whitelist: [allFilenamesExceptJavaScript] })] // Don't bundle .js files from node_modules
});

module.exports = [clientBundleConfig, serverBundleConfig];
```

and my project.json, where on publish should call for webpack with --env.prod

```js
//.......
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postcompile": [
      "cmd /c echo Removing read-only attributes in %project:Directory%\\bin\\ && cmd /c attrib -r  %project:Directory%\\bin\\* /s",
      "cmd /c echo Removing read-only attributes in %project:Directory%\\..\\packages\\ && cmd /c attrib -r  %project:Directory%\\..\\packages\\* /s"
    ],
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },
//...
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, I deploy using the vs2015 build menu -> Publish [projet name]

Comment: Only change the publicPath parameter for '/' and read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/44079278/7143288